# Split array into evenly-distributed chunks

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

I'm looking for an efficient way to split an array into chunks that have a similar histogram.

For example, given the array:

```
l = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 55, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 2, 2, 21, 2])
```

I would like to obtain:

```
c1 = np.array([1, 4, 1, 5, 5, 3, 2])
c2 = np.array([2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 2])
c3 = np.array([3, 1, 2, 55, 5, 2, 21])
```

Not only this but each chunk should have a similar size and a similar sum on a given function f:

```
1. |sum(ci, f) - sum(cj, f)| < e, for i != j
2. |len(ci) - len(cj)| < e, for i != j
```

where

```
sum(c, f) = f(c[0]) + ... + f(c[len(c)])
```

**Edit:**
To clarify the intention of this. I want to parallelize a process over a list into `n` sub-processes but the cost has to be distributed among each sub-process evenly. The cost of processing an element in this list is a function `f` of the integer at the same position in array `l`, where f is the computational complexity of the process. For example, `f(i)=i^2`. So, I want all processes to have the same computational cost and not to have processes that finish too early while others last forever.

Comment: Please share how you get c1, c2, and c3 above.

Comment: Finally, finally. Thank you, sir, for giving a _minimal_ example.

Comment: @mskimm: I did it manually. The way to obtain them is precisely what I am asking...

Comment: If you need to parallelize a series of jobs. Any reason why you can't use the original array as a queue for all the workers?

Comment: @M4rtini: yes, the reason is that I am using Condor (a distributed computation framework), so I don't have a pool of tasks. I need to specify the tasks beforehand (before submitting the job to Condor's server).

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with a very weak assumption that *similar histograms* are defined in a following rudimentary way: for a set of integers *S1*, the histogram `H(S1)` is similar to an histogram `H(S2)` of set *S2* if `sum(S1) = sum(S2)`.

Generally you are after finding subsets *S1, S2, ..., SN* of an array *A* such that `f(S1) = f(S2) = ... = f(SN)`, and where under our assumptions `f=sum`. Unfortunately you've got yourself a **[k-Partition problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem)**, which is NP-hard, and if you'll get someone to find an efficient way (ie poly-time) to do that, as you requested, the consequence would be that `P=NP` was proven to be true first on **stackoverflow**!

Comment: I think that I don't need to have such an exact partition. I can relax the problem and have some approximation. For example, I could loop (in some smart way) through the sorted list to evenly distribute over the set of chunks. So, for example: `l= [20, 19, 7, 7, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1]` --> `c1 = [20, 3, 2], c2 = [19, 4, 1], c3 = [7, 7, 1]`. Here I changed the direction of assigning in the chunks every 3 steps. what do you think?

Comment: @Kits89 Relaxing the problem and having a poly-time approximation are different things. It could be that after you relax the problem there is a polynomial solution, no need to approximate and many NP-hard problems become polynomial when certain conditions or assumptions change. That aside, you may to start here for 3-PARTITION: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/82332/seeking-a-solution-algorithm-to-the-3-partition-problem and follow the links to see if you can adapt an approximation for your particular case.